# SQLITE (dificil) Es posible seleccionar solo la columna en la que se cumpla la condición?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Tengo una tabla similar a la siguiente:

| ID | product1 | strategy1 | product2 | strategy2 | product3 | strategy3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A | 3 | C | 4 | P |
| 2 | 22 | B | 10 | A | 5 | A |
| 2 | 22 | X | 6 | F | 5 | A |

En otra tabla tengo producto y estrategia.

| producto | estrategia | identificador |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 1 |

Nada de store procedures, esto debe realizarlo solo la consulta.(viene incrustado en un js)

Bien, quisiera filtrar sobre la segunda tabla sobre el criterio producto y estrategia de la primera de la manera más performante que exista.
Es decir que me devuelva un

```
SELECT product*, strategy* 
where (product1 = 10  and strategy1 = A) OR (product2 = 10  and strategy2 = A) OR (product3 = 10  and strategy3 = A)
```

El problema radica en cómo poder devolver solo las columnas que tengan esa combinación.

Por ejemplo product1,strategy1 en el primer row y en el segundo product2, strategy2.

Realmente es posible? Trabajo con SQLITE.

Comment: Esto parece un problema de diseño, ¿que va a pasar si llegas a tener 100 productos? ¿Agregarás un par de columnas a la tabla por cada nuevo producto?

Comment: No podes construir un sql, porque tu tabla no esta normalizada... con una tabla normalizada, no tendrias este problema...

Comment: Opino igual, pero no es mi software, es la aplicación a la que le debo brindar desarrollo de mantenimiento. Multiples clientes trabajan con la aplicación y el modulo requiere un nuevo criterio.

Comment: Poder se puede, es enroscado y queda feo, pero con un `IF` viendo que se cumplan las mismas condiciones que en el `WHERE`. También con un haciendo `UNION` de las 3 condiciones separadas

Comment: Pude resolverlo dividiendo todos los campos en muchas subqueries , por ejemplo select product de la tabla 2 where produc IN (select product1 where condicion) or (select product2 where condicion). No creo que exista forma mas performante. De todas formas la sintaxis es asquerosa.